# Why does my div disappear on desktop view with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The div and the link work fine in mobile view. However, when I extend to desktop view, the child element disappears leaving both the h1 tags positioned in the same place?. What am I doing wrong?

The flex layout worked great before I added the link inside the container so I don't know what the problem is.

**HTML:**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  .banner-container{
    display: flex;
  }
}

.main-banner{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #D9B784;
  background-color: #D9B784;
  margin: 1%;
  min-height: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
  filter: grayscale(0%); 
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.main-banner:hover{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(75%); 
  filter: grayscale(75%); 
}

.clothing-banner{
  background-image: url("../img/banner1.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.accessories-banner{
  background-image: url("../img/acc.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1{
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container">
  <a href="https://www.redpostequestrian.co.uk/clothing/holland-cooper">
    <div class="clothing-container">
      <div class="main-banner clothing-banner">
        <h1>Clothing</h1>
      </div>
   <a>
  </div>
  <div class="accessories-container">
    <a href="https://www.redpostequestrian.co.uk/accessories/holland-cooper">
      <div class="main-banner accessories-banner">
        <h1>Accessories</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main issue:**
The anchor `<a>` element had no size, therefore it collapsed. 
It had to do with errors in your markup. You forgot to close some `<div>`- and the `<a>` elements.

**Flexbox issue:**
If you want to use `flexbox` you need to set a size for the items. In this case, I set the `flex` property for the two elements: "Clothing" and "Accessories". Something like:

```css
flex: 100% 1 0; /* shorthand for: flex-basis, flex-grow, flex-shrink */
```

---

**Recommendations:**
You can read here for more insights on flexbox-properties: [flexbox-css-guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can write your markup a bit more efficient (it depends on what your goals are). For example you don't have to wrap a `<div>` inside an `<a>`-tag. Instead you can use the `<a>`-element as the `container` and discard the `<div>` completly.

`<a>`-elements are not `block` elements, therefore you can either set `display: block` to make them cover all the `child-elements` or use it as a `child-element` of a `container` that uses either `flexbox` or `grid`. In this case, you don't have to modify the display property in order to work (as you can see in the example below).

---

**Working example (with modification to the markup):**

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .banner-container {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.main-banner {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #D9B784;
  background-color: #D9B784;
  margin: 1%;
  min-height: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: filter .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.clothing, .accessories {
  flex: 100% 1 0;
}

.main-banner:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(75%);
  filter: grayscale(75%);
}

.clothing-banner {
  background-image: url("../img/banner1.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.accessories-banner {
  background-image: url("../img/acc.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container">
  <a href="https://www.redpostequestrian.co.uk/clothing/holland-cooper" class="clothing">
    <div class="main-banner clothing-banner">
      <h1>Clothing</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="accessories-container">
  <a href="https://www.redpostequestrian.co.uk/accessories/holland-cooper" class="accessories">
    <div class="main-banner accessories-banner">
      <h1>Accessories</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT: Added simple two column layout**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">col-1</div>
  <div class="col">col-2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I change it so that in desktop view, "clothing" and "accessories" splits into two columns?

Comment: @JulienLittler No problem. If this has answered your question please consider marking the answer as accepted. I've added a simple example on how to do a simple two columns layout with flexbox.